# Cumulative Monthly Reporting by Salesperson

Tags: excel, windows-8, excel-2013

Below there is a link into my file, in which i'm having trouble to get monthly cumulative data. I want to get final Cumulative monthly data according to the salesperson and the product type. By cumulative i mean for example, if I choose May I want to get collective data starting from July till May.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx5QZn9WpBBOT1VtX3hSOTJMVlE

Comment: And if it was February would you want March to February? If so you are basically asking for the whole row.

Comment: It's like showing data starting from the beginning of the year and considering the reporting year begins with July 1, if it is February it should give the data from July to February

Answer (score 0):

The SUMPRODUCT() formula will do what you want:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$2:$F$330=B$2)*($G$2:$G$330=$A3)*$H$2:INDEX($H$2:$S$330,0,MATCH($A$1,$H$1:$S$1)))
```

There are three parts.  The first two find the correct rows.  The last sets the full range.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much sir. It works correctly if we add match type at the end. But my problem is Data table and Summary table (the one with formulas) are located in different sheets and I don't want to mess my summary sheet up so it needs to stay that way. This way the last part of the function doesn't work.
Changed it like this and it returns #Value--

Data!$I$15:INDEX(this part works i suppose)

Comment: Changed formula is =SUMPRODUCT((Data!$A$15:$A$343=E$6)*(Data!$B$15:$B$343=E$4)*(Data!$F$15:$F$343=$B7)*Data!$I$15:INDEX(Data!I15:T343,0,MATCH(MONTH(DATEVALUE($D$2&" 1")),Data!$I$13:$T$13,0))) - Months are shown as dates so i had to convert them to month number which should work i think. I13:T13 are month numbers. And D2 is our data validation cell.  I think problem is with this part Data!$I$15:INDEX(Data!I15:T343,0,MATCH(MONTH(DATEVALUE($D$2&" 1")),Data!$I$13:$T$13,0))